# efeito de 3d em janelas do prédio

Tags: javascript, html, css

Como fazer esse efeito de janelas mais pra fora e outras mais para dentro?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A gambi que eu tenho até o momento:

```css
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 perspective: 900px;
 perspective-origin: 100% 100%;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
  transform: translateZ(-1000px) rotateY(0turn);
 }
  to {
  transform: translateZ(-1000px) rotateY(1turn);
 }
}
body > div {
 height: calc(11 * 15vmin);
 position: relative;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transition: transform 1s;
  animation: rotation 5s infinite;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -400px;
}
body > div > div {
 width: 60vmin;
 height: calc(11 * 15vmin);
 position: absolute;
 background-color: black;
}
#front {
 background-color: skyblue;
 padding: 0 20vmin;
 transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(30vmin);
}
#back {
 transform: rotateY(180deg) translate3d(-20vmin, 0vmin, 30vmin) scaleX(1.7);
}
#right {
 transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(70vmin);
}
#left {
 transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(30vmin);
}
#top {
 height: 100vmin;
 transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(0);
}
#bottom {
 height: 100vmin;
 transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(0);
}

div.left {
 float: left;
}
div.right {
 float: right;
}
div.col1 {
 width: 15vmin;
}
div.col2 {
 width: 30vmin;
}
div.col3 {
 width: 45vmin;
}
div.row1 {
 height: 15vmin;
}
div.row2 {
 height: 30vmin;
}
div.row3 {
 height: 45vmin;
}

div.top-1 {
 margin-top: -15vmin;
}
div.left1 {
 margin-left: 15vmin;
}

.red {
 background-color: #eedfd1;
}
.green {
 background-color: #ceffbb;
}
.yellow {
 background-color: #e4ffc6;
}
.blue {
 background-color: #c2fce2;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="front">
            <div class="col1 row2 left blue"></div>
            <div class="col1 row1 left green"></div>
            <div class="col1 row1 left yellow"></div>
            <div class="col1 row1 left red"></div>
            <div class="col2 row1 left red"></div>
            <div class="col1 row2 right green"></div>
            <div class="col1 row1 left green"></div>
            <div class="col1 row1 left yellow"></div>
            <div class="col1 row1 left blue"></div>
            <div class="col2 row2 left blue"></div>
            <div class="col1 row1 left yellow"></div>
            <div class="col1 row1 left blue"></div>
            <div class="col2 row1 left red"></div>
            <div class="col1 row1 left yellow"></div>
            <div class="col1 row1 left red"></div>
            <div class="col1 row2 left green"></div>
            <div class="col1 row1 left yellow"></div>
            <div class="col1 row3 right blue"></div>
            <div class="col1 row1 left top-1 green"></div>
            <div class="col1 row1 left top-1 left1 blue"></div>
            <div class="col3 row1 left yellow"></div>
            <div class="col1 row1 left red"></div>
            <div class="col1 row1 left blue"></div>
            <div class="col1 row1 left green"></div>
            <div class="col1 row2 left yellow"></div>
            <div class="col1 row1 left red"></div>
            <div class="col1 row1 left red"></div>
            <div class="col1 row1 left red"></div>
            <div class="col1 row1 left blue"></div>
            <div class="col1 row1 left green"></div>
            <div class="col1 row1 left green"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="back"></div>
        <div id="left"></div>
        <div id="right"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: A sua intensão é fazer o "prédio" inteiro rodar dessa forma mesmo? Cara muito provavelmente vc precisaria de criar um cubo no lugar de cada uma dessas janelas, e colocar uns mais para frente que os outros ai talvez com a perspectiva fique próximo do que vc quer. E reflita.... nem tudo vale a pena fazer com CSS, E reflita que muito do que vc ve por ai foi feito em algum software e depois exportado no "formato web" como os SVG por exemplo que quase todos são feitos em softwres, dificilmente alguem desenha um SVG mais complexo na mão

Comment: Da uma olhada nos trabalhos da Ana Tudor que as vezes vc acha uma base para te ajudar, ou só pra ver umas técnicas mesmo https://codepen.io/thebabydino/

Comment: @hugocsl, sim, a ideia é fazer uma maquete 3d para o usuário interagir. Saberia me recomendar um software, preferencialmente gratuito?

Comment: Cara não vou saber dizer, mas te falo que vc vai precisar construir as 4 faces do bloco... O indicado mesmo seria fazer isso em um software 3D e exportar um Gif, mas se vc quer quer um elemento interativo ai vai complicar mesmo.... Olha aqui e vai dando next para ver se aparece algo que te serve https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pens/public/34/

Comment: Valeu @hugocsl, dei uma olhada, e, em geral, só tem alguns cubos que posso me basear, vou ter que quebrar a cabeça nisso, tenho menos de uma semana e é a primeira vez que mexo com css 3d

Comment: Lembrei de tu https://codepen.io/Gthibaud/pen/qyQryx

Comment: @hugocsl não sou ninja pra fazer isso só com css puro, no final o chefe desistiu de fazer isso, ficou só uma tabela com os números dos apartamentos, mas valeu pela ajuda